# snwoflake issue with date format in a stored procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I don't understand my issue with date format in a stored procedure call back.

```
    create or replace procedure dailybucket()
  returns varchar
  language javascript
  as     
  $$  
    var my_sql_command = "SELECT current_date()";
    var statement1 = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: my_sql_command} );
    var result_set1 = statement1.execute();
    result_set1.next();
    var column1 = result_set1.getColumnValue(1);
      return column1;
  $$
  ;
```

When i do SELECT current_date() i get the date format as :
`2020-01-14`

When i do a callback from my function call dailybucket() i get a full date ... :
`Tue Jan 14 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)`

Anyone have an idea how to retrieve data format only from function return ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this one?

```
create or replace procedure dailybucket()
returns varchar
language javascript
as     
$$  
  var my_sql_command = "SELECT to_char(current_date())";
  var statement1 = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: my_sql_command} );
  var result_set1 = statement1.execute();
  result_set1.next();
  var column1 = result_set1.getColumnValue(1);
    return column1;
$$
;
```

As I understand, the JavaScript variable turns the short date to full date.